# Работа с таблицами в FireBase

Tags: javascript, база-данных, firebase, firebase-database

Как я могу редактировать/добавлять записи в таблицах Firebase? 
Официальные документация предлагает делать так:

```
function writeUserData(name) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + '1').set({
    name: 'newUserName'
  });
}
```

В firebase я соответственно имею следующую структуру бд:

```
app738b
    -users
        -1
          -name: 'username'
```

После этого поле name должно измениться, но ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function writeUserData(username) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + '1').set({
    name: username
  });
}
```

Comment: спасибо. Но это понятно, что имя не хардкодится, я вставил это для примера. В реальном приложении я передаю его аргументом.